# How to add data to last selected and default index using SegmentControl ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using Segment Control.
it contains two data. and one data is default and i need to display default in segment.

I am setting default data like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib 
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [priceOptionSeg addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueDidChange:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self assignDO:priceList];
}

- (void)assignDO:(NSMutableArray *)inputList 
{
    for (int x = 0; x < inputList.count; x++) 
    {
        if (tempDO.price_is_default == YES) 
        {
            [priceOptionSeg setSelectedSegmentIndex:x];
            NSLog(@"%ld",(long) priceOptionSeg.selectedSegmentIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am mananing index like this way:

```
- (void)segmentedControlValueDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) 
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"First was selected");
            break;

        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Second was selected");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I am able to add default value in segment control.
I can change values in segment.
suppose I select 2nd segment 
but when I move to next controller and back to my controller segment is at first index.i want like if i move to next controller but when I come at my controller. last selected segment should be there
what to do

Comment: Do you use push and pop on your navigation controller to move between the two controllers? If yes, the method viewDidLoad: won't be called when you come back and the data should remain the same.. in which method do you call the for cycle?

Comment: @JacopoPenzo i am adding segment control in tableview cell and adding data in that

Comment: @JacopoPenzo please check update question

Comment: you have take one global variable and store segment clicked index and reuse it when come back

Comment: @Birendra save index in segmentedControlValueDidChange method?

Comment: yes when you have move to next view

Comment: global variable everytime it return 0 when i use     _lastIndexPath = priceOptionSeg.selectedSegmentIndex;

Comment: where you have declare global variable?

Comment: in h file of tableview cell

Comment: use appdelegate to declare global variable

Comment: ok.can you answer queston?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *index;

create onbject in .h file
 AppDelegate *appDel;
and use it in .m
appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: use the ViewController class to store selected index instead of appdelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ViewController.h` declared int like

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)int selectedIndex;
```

in `ViewDidLoad` assign the default value

```
self.selectedIndex = 0;
```

in `CellForRowAtIndexpath` selected index

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Create you custom class cell here
    ..
    [cell.priceOptionSeg addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueDidChange:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.priceOptionSeg setSelectedSegmentIndex:self.selectedIndex];
    ..
}
```

and add the value change action of segment in same view controller

```
- (void)segmentedControlValueDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) 
    {
        case 0:
            self.selectedIndex = 0;
            break;

        case 1:
            self.selectedIndex = 1;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

From your existing Cell SubClass remove Following line

```
[priceOptionSeg addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueDidChange:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: i am getting default value and i have to display in segment.i am adding in custom cell. when i change controller.last selected segment should be selected

Comment: than what should change in code in tableview cell which i add in question

Comment: by default option is selected from server.may be one index or other

Comment: No problem. whenever you want to change default selected index set self.selectedIndex and reload the cell or tableview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129021/discussion-between-mahesh-and-divine-child).

Comment: You there in chat discussion?